# Is it possible to see which Oblivion mods a save relies on?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Having transferred my Oblivion save file from my old computer to a new one, I don't remember all mods I had on the old computer (which I don't have access to anymore).

Apart from guessing, is there any other way of knowing which mods was used with the save file?

P.S. AFAIK, I didn't use Oblivion Mod Manager.

Comment: I guess you won't be able to get access again in the future? What I did was after installing Oblivion on my new PC, I copy/pasted my Oblivion program files folder to transfer all the mods.

Comment: I would have done the same myself, but the bits (literally bits), are long gone, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! [Wrye Bash](http://wryemusings.com/Wrye%20Bash.html) has a savefile browser tab that will show you a save's "master list", which is the list of mod files (and their order) that the save file depends on for all its object IDs.

Comment: AFAIR, Wrye Bash show you all the mod you had on your save, not just the `.esm` (at least that's what the screenshot shows).

Comment: @Jupotter: IIRC, the tracking of ESP files in the save is something that Wrye Bash does internally, not something stored in the save file format, so once the save is separated from an install of WB that information is lost. However, it's been a long time—if the OP tries this method they'll be able to confirm what shows up in WB.

Comment: I've got save files from other people and from my previous computers that all show the `.esp` dependencies just fine.

Comment: @William Awesome. Specifically, does it show `.esp` files that you don't have? If so, then WB is even better for this than I thought!

Comment: @Seven: Yes, it does show `.esp` files that I don't have =)

Answer (score 1):

**Oblivion mod manager** http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=2097

This is a utility for managing plugins, and also for packing them for distribution. It can be used either as an enhanced version of the oblivion launcher's data files selector, or as a more advanced mod manager when mods are specially packed into omod files.

Also included are several utilities, such as a BSA unpacker, **save file manager for syncing your active plugin list to a save game**, conflict detector, archiveinvalidation.txt generator and more.

Comment: This kind of sync only turns on and off plugins you already have installed to match the savefile. It won't tell you what you don't have installed.